# How do I get syncdb db_table and app_label to play nicely together

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a model that looks something like this:

```
class HeiselFoo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        """ Meta """
        app_label = "Foos"
        db_table = u"medley_heiselfoo_heiselfoo"
```

And whenever I run my test suite, I get an error because Django isn't creating the tables for that model.

It appears to be an interaction between app_label and db_table -- as the test suite runs normally if db_table is set, but app_label isn't.

Here's a link to the full source code: http://github.com/cmheisel/heiselfoo

Here's the traceback from the test suite:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_truth (heiselfoo.tests.HeiselFooTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/heiselfoo/tests.py", line 10, in test_truth
    f.save()
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 434, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 527, in save_base
    result = manager._insert(values, return_id=update_pk, using=using)
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 195, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, values, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1479, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 783, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLInsertCompiler, self).execute_sql(None)
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/chris/Code/heiselfoo/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 200, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: no such table: medley_heiselfoo_heiselfoo

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
Creating test database 'default'...
No fixtures found.
medley_heiselfoo_heiselfoo
Destroying test database 'default'...
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I'm a moron. You need to have an app in INSTALLED_APPS that matches your app_label or your tables won't get created.

Answer (score 2):

> You need to have an app in INSTALLED_APPS that matches your app_label or your tables won't get created.

In my case it doesn't work - when I change app name in INSTALLED_APPS on app_label wchich matches models Meta setting, but is different than app folder name, *manage.py syncdb* raise: "Error: No module named ...". I still have no idea how to sync models with database in case of using app_label and db_table in model Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: this is not a direct answer to your question.

From looking at your code in github I find that you have defined the model inside `models.py`. And yet you have defined `app_label` inside your model's `Meta`. Is there a reason for doing this?

Django's [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) says that `app_label` is meant to be used

> If a model exists outside of the standard `models.py` (for instance, if the app’s models are in submodules of `myapp.models`), the model must define which app it is part of:

Given that, I don't see any reason to define an `app_label` in your case. Hence my question. Perhaps you are better off without defining the `app_label` after all.

Comment: Manoj, thanks. The reason I'm defining an app_label is because for purposes of the admin, I want the model to appear under a different label than "heiselfoo" because I'm extending and overriding some models in a 3rd party app, and I want my models to appear under that app_label.